# Error when using Django SVN version

Tags: python, django

I've written some code that works fine when I use Django 1.1, but raises an exception when I use the SVN version:

```
class TribeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    slug = forms.SlugField(max_length=20,
        help_text = _("a short version of the name consisting only of letters, numbers, underscores and hyphens."),
        error_message = _("This value must contain only letters, numbers, underscores and hyphens.")
        )

    def clean_slug(self):
        if Tribe.objects.filter(slug__iexact=self.cleaned_data["slug"]).count() > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("A tribe already exists with that slug."))
        return self.cleaned_data["slug"].lower()

    def clean_name(self):
        if Tribe.objects.filter(name__iexact=self.cleaned_data["name"]).count() > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("A tribe already exists with that name."))
        return self.cleaned_data["name"]

    class Meta:
        model = Tribe
        fields = ('name', 'slug', 'description')
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Don't post a huge gif of the traceback page. There is a very useful link on that very page which says 'switch to copy and paste view'. Click thqt, and post the text it gives you.

Comment: Seems your code is compatible with 1.1 but you're almost 3 subversion late.

Answer (score 0):

It's saying error_message was an unexpected keyword argument. Try error_messages instead: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#error-messages

Comment: It's bizarre that it works in 1.1. Maybe they deprecated error_message  (singular) and it hasn't been until now that they've enforced the plural form.

Comment: It was added in 1.0 as `error_messages`, so I doubt the OP is using version 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Error message passed from one error message to un unlimited number and 's' was added. Error messages are not expected to be added as a dictionary, not a string.